# Using URL Redirection based on domain name using UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, urlrewriting.net

I want to redirect a request in an asp.net web site based on the domain, my scenario is like this.

I have the app setup so  that it will process the requests from multiple domains like from `www.abc.com` and `www.xyz.com`, now i want that when ever a request comes to the `www.abc.com/default.aspx` the url would be rewrites to the `www.abc.com/custom/abcdefault.aspx` while for all the other requests like for `www.xyz.com/default.aspx` it should do nothing.

I am currently using the `UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter` for the URL rewriting,

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something along this:

```
<add name=”Redirect_abc.com”  virtualUrl=”^http\://www.abc.com/default.aspx”
rewriteUrlParameter=”ExcludeFromClientQueryString”
destinationUrl=”http://www.xyz.com/custom/abc.default.aspx″
redirect=”Domain”
redirectMode=”Permanent”
ignoreCase=”true” />
```

This just matches the pattern you specified before but can easily be changed to match another patetrn.

Regards

Jonathan